# shuffle a find search without completing the whole search

Tags: bash, find

Is there a way to obtain a result similar to this (I need to do it using bash):

```
find path -type f -name 'key' | shuf | head -n100
```

without completing the entire search? I need to get 100 random samples but cannot wait for the find command to finish the whole search.

I could do something like this

```
find path -type f -name 'key' -print | head -nN | shuf | head -n100
```

(with N > 100)

but obviously it is not the correct solution (as the search will always return the same N samples, so I would not search in the whole set of files).

If it has a trivial solution, I am not aware on it and I apologise.

Comment: How random does it need to be? Quite by definition, it can't be so random as to include things that would have been at the end of the search's results until that search reaches its end.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? How quickly does your data change? Can you cache an old listing, shuffle it, and then filter for items that still exist? You'd lose the ability to find new items, but at least you'd have a fast shuffle.

Comment: On a similar note, you could shuffle output cached by the `locate` cron job.

Comment: Directory structure looks like:
mainfolder/year/station/julianday.file
Yes, I think your solution of caching an old listing is a good option, as the data does not change "too quickly".
I was more thinking about something like "randomize the path in which find will search", does this not exist?
I will try your second suggesiton too (locate cron job).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: ...to be clear, the reason I ask about the directory structure is that if you've got a bunch of directories (and all files are in onesuch), you could shuffle the order in which you want to search them. Wouldn't give you an even distribution, but still you'd have full coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter way to do it :

```
find path -type f -name 'key' | shuf --head-count=100
```

Comment: Is that at all different from `shuf | head -n 100` in terms of how much of `find` output it consumes?

Comment: Not tested for real, maybe not

Comment: Tested it, it's not _that_ faster, just shorter as described, and it's logical

Answer (score 1):

Following Charles Duffy suggestions, I am using now something like this

```
for (( i=0; i<100; i++)); do
  for d in `find mainfolder/my_case_simple_directory_structure_/.../* -maxdepth 1 -type d | shuf | head -n1`; do
    find $d -type f -name 'key' | shuf | head -n1
  done
done
```

It is not the optimal solution, but it works for my case, with a quite simple directory structure.

Thanks.